# Setting Android listeners in Kotlin - usage of return in lambdas

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, listener

Consider this listener code:

```
        expandable_list.setOnChildClickListener { expandableListView, view, groupPosition, childPosition, l ->
        Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                listDataHeader[groupPosition]
                        + " : "
                        + listDataChild[listDataHeader[groupPosition]]!![childPosition],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return false}
```

It won't work, and I am getting "return is not allowed here" error form IDE. I've searched a bit and it turns out explicit returns do not work in lambdas, but the signature of the method I am trying to use is:

`public final fun setOnChildClickListener(onChildClickListener:((ExpandableListView!, View!, Int, Int, Long) -> Boolean)! : Unit`

My workaround is to define my listener logic in a separate function that returns Boolean like so:

```
    private fun myBooleanReturningFun(): Boolean {
    Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "I work from here",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return false
}
```

and then call it inside my listener:

```
expandable_list.setOnChildClickListener { expandableListView, view, groupPosition, childPosition, l ->
            myBooleanReturningFun()
        }
```

But is this the right or the most Kotlin way to do it? How would I need to change my listener code to **work without defining a separate function that returns a Boolean**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it this way, without return word

```
expandable_list.setOnChildClickListener { expandableListView, view, groupPosition, childPosition, l ->
    Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            listDataHeader[groupPosition]
                    + " : "
                    + listDataChild[listDataHeader[groupPosition]]!![childPosition],
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    false}
```